# Is there a way to switch on partial strings in c#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pattern-matching

I have a list of different types of images I need to store in a database, they all have a type description such as `Indoor` or `GardenSummer` and things like that, but there are a lot of the descriptions that contain repeated words, like `GardenSummer` and `AreaSummer1KM` for example both contain "Summer", so is there a way for me to do something like this in c#:

```
open System

let strs = ["Kitchen"; "GardenSummer"; "GardenWinter"; "AreaSummer1KM"; "PoolIndoors"; "LivingRoom"; "BathRoom"]

let switch (x: string) = match x with
    | a when a.Contains "Summer"    -> Some "Summer"  // here
    | b when b.Contains "Winter"    -> Some "Winter"  // here
    | "Exterior" | "ParkFacilities" -> Some "Outdoors"
    | "Kitchen"  | "Landing"        -> Some "Indoors"
    | c when c.Contains "Room"      -> Some "Indoors" // and here
    | _                             -> None


let sorted = List.map switch strs

// part from here and down was just added to print the contents, and isn't a part of the issue
let printOption = function
    | Some v -> v.ToString () |> Console.WriteLine
    | None   -> "No Match"    |> Console.WriteLine

List.iter printOption sorted
```

is there a way for me to switch on str.Contains(str2) without making a bunch of `else if`s?

Comment: Isn't this a simple switch statement (or a condition)? Sure you can do this in C#, via switch or condition.

Comment: look what it says `a when a.Contains "Summer"` in c# you can't write `case a.Contains("Summer"):` because of lack of pattern matching

Comment: You can write a condition: if a.Contains("Summer"). Actually I don't see the need of using switch at all

Comment: like `case if(...):`?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee, no you can't, cases must be constant values.

Comment: No. Like if. Remove the case and switch completely. A switch statement is basically a restricted version of a condition.

Comment: yeah, but I want to avoid having a lot of ifs

Comment: Can you please explain me the advantage of using a switch over a set of ifs? Other than building a much less adaptable code?

Comment: building a much more adaptable code, having a ton of ifs is limiting and cluttered, with pattern matching I can just add another case that satisfies a condition with minimal amounts of code

Comment: (I will have to cut this conversation because I tend to extend comments too much and have been warned by moderators various times already...) I am not saying that you should create a big amount of ifs; this would indicate a wrongly-structured code. But if you do that, using ifs or using switch is basically the same as far as they occupy more or less the same space. I honestly don't see the point of using switch at all (unless under very specific conditions where the code might look slightly "nicer"). But if you prefer switch is completely up to you.

Comment: I updated the code to better illustrate what I want to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The slightly longer answer is "no, for a good reason". The `switch` statement is actually quite a smart statement, that performs better than a chain of `if`-`else if` statements in many cases (a good example being the typical `switch (MessageType) ...`). To do this, however, it requires certain contracts to be held. In the end, it *doesn't* evaluate every possibility. It performs something similar to a binary search on the possible options.

In the end, your F# code probably does the equivalent of `if`-`else if` statements, rather than the equivalent of `switch` in C#.

Of course, nothing prevents you from creating your own method that would be syntactically similar to F#'s `match`. Anonymous delegates, generic functions, all those make it rather easy to write such syntax shorteners :)

And of course, there's other options too, like using regular expressions or such. Calling `Contains` 10 times in a row is going to mean a significant performance penalty if the searched string is long.

Some sample regexes for your data and switches. The common code is as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = 
    new [] 
    {
      "Kitchen", "GardenSummer", "GardenWinter", "AreaSummer1KM", 
      "PoolIndoors", "LivingRoom", "BathRoom", "Exterior", "ParkFacilities"
    };

    foreach (var str in data)
    {
      Matcher(str).Dump();
    }
}
```

Now the thing we're going to change is the `Matcher` method implementation.

First, to just simplify the whole thing and avoid multiple string matching (comparing strings isn't exactly free):

```
Regex matcherRegex = new Regex("(Summer)|(Winter)|(^Exterior|ParkFacilities$)", 
                               RegexOptions.Compiled);
string Matcher(string input)
{
  var m = matcherRegex.Match(input);

  if (m.Groups.Count == 4)
  {
    if (m.Groups[0].Success) return "Summer";
    else if (m.Groups[1].Success) return "Winter";
    else if (m.Groups[2].Success) return "Outdoors";
  }

  return null;
}
```

So, we still have a if-else chain, but we no longer traverse the strings multiple times. It also allows you to easily specify the conditions you want.

One way to improve this to be more "switchy" is by using LINQ. This is definitely not something you want to do for performance reasons, it's only about aesthetics:

```
var groupIndex = m.Groups.OfType<Group>()
                         .Skip(1)
                         .Select((i, idx) => new { Item = i, Index = idx + 1 })
                         .Where(i => i.Item.Success)
                         .Select(i => i.Index)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
switch (groupIndex)
{
  case 0: return null;
  case 1: return "Summer";
  case 2: return "Winter";
  case 3: return "Outdoors";
}
```

Basically, I get the index of the matched group, and use a switch on that. As I said before, this is probably going to be slower than the first variant, at least due to the LINQ overhead.

You can also use named captures to get the matched groups by name, rather than by index, which is a bit more maintainable. Also, for simple cases, you could use the named group name to avoid the switch altogether:

```
Regex matcherRegex = 
  new Regex("(?<Summer>Summer)"
            + "|(?<Winter>Winter)"
            + "|(?<Outdoors>(^Exterior|ParkFacilities$))", 
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

string Matcher(string input)
{
  return matcherRegex.Match(input)
         .Groups
         .OfType<Group>()
         .Select((i, idx) => new { Item = i, Index = idx })
         .Skip(1)
         .Where(i => i.Item.Success)
         .Select(i => matcherRegex.GroupNameFromNumber(i.Index))
         .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

All of those are just samples, you may want to change those for better edge case or exception handling, and performance, but it shows the ideas.

The last version in particular is handy in that there's nothing preventing you from using this as a common method that handles all the string "switches" that you can explain in regular expressions. Sadly, group names allow a lot of unicode characters, but not whitespaces; it's nothing you couldn't work around, though.

You could even build the pattern matcher automatically, for example by passing `Expression<Func<...>>` to a helper method, but that's going into complicated territory :)

Comment: @varocarbas The question explicitly states "is there a way for me to switch on str.Contains(str2) without making a bunch of else ifs?"

Comment: Well... you are certainly right. I did just read the code and the intention (converting). In that case, your "no" is motivated. Will delete my comment right now and +1 this.

Comment: sure but using regex puts me in the same situation, right? since every case would be a different regex pattern, which brings us back to the same problem

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Every pattern doesn't have to be a regex. For example, your case would be matched by `(Summer|Winter)`. Now you don't search the whole string twice anymore. I'll update my answer to show a few samples.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Updated the answer as promised.